# Customizing objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please help me with this customization of objects in javascript, I'm a little stuck.

**Object**

```
var stocks = [
{
    "size": "2",
    "count": 5,
    "store": {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Belconnen"
    }
},
{
    "size": "3",
    "count": 4,
    "store": {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Canberra"
    }
},
{
    "size": "4",
    "count": 4,
    "store": {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Bankstown"
    }
},
{
    "size": "5",
    "count": 5,
    "store": {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Canberra"
    }
}];
```

**Expected Output**

```
{3:{"sizes": {2: 3}}},
{4:{"sizes": {3: 3, 5: 3}}},
{5:{"sizes": {4: 3}}}
```

My code so far

```
for (var key in stocks) {
    var stock = stocks[key];

    stores[stock.store.id] = stock.store;
    var store = stores[stock.store.id];

    if (!store.sizes || !store.sizes.length) {
        store.sizes = [stock.size];
    }
}
```

But it keeps overiding the first size value of the store.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is kinda called transforming objects! And the expected output is not even valid, er... Kinda valid.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and where are you stuck.

Comment: `for(var key in stocks){
   var stock = stocks[key];

   stores[stock.store.id] = stock.store;
   var store = stores[stock.store.id];

   if(!store.sizes || !store.sizes.length){
    store.sizes = [stock.size];
   }

   //console.log(stock);
  }` it keeps overiding the first value of the size in the store.

Comment: @al.zheic Update it in your question by [edit]ing the post.

Comment: @al.zheic What is stocks and stores ?

Comment: Neither your input nor your output are a single object. Are they supposed to be arrays of objects for which you forgot to show the `[` and `]`?

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to solve the problem

```js
    var stocks = [
    {"size": 2, "count": 3, "store": {"id": 3, "name": "Canberra"}}, 
    {"size": 3, "count": 3, "store": {"id": 4, "name": "Belconnen"}},
    {"size": 4, "count": 3, "store": {"id": 5, "name": "Bankstown"}},
    {"size": 5, "count": 3, "store": {"id": 4, "name": "Belconnen"}}];
    
    var obj = {};
    
    stocks.forEach(function(item){
        // initialize if object key not present
        if(!obj[item.store.id]){
           obj[item.store.id] = {"sizes": {}};
        }
        obj[item.store.id]["sizes"][item.size] = item.count;  
    });
    
    console.log(obj);
```

Here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/flyinggambit/nc3uny53/

Check the console window for fiddle output